# In shell, How to export the 'sed' command output into environment variables

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I have `replace.sh` file. would like to replace `#HOSTNAME` into actual value 'mylocalhostname'.
In order to achieve I have used below command. but unable to make it.

```
printenv | grep "#HOSTNAME" | sed "s/#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/1" | xargs export
```

Environment variable looks like below

```
export HOSTNAME=mylocalhostname
export jdbc_url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=#HOSTNAME
export jdbc_url_2=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=#HOSTNAME
export jdbc_url_3=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=#HOSTNAME
export jdbc_url_4=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=#HOSTNAME
```

**Expected Output:**

```
#printenv
HOSTNAME=mylocalhostname
jdbc_url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=mylocalhostname
jdbc_url_2=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=mylocalhostname
jdbc_url_3=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=mylocalhostname
jdbc_url_4=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.aws.com/dbname?ApplicationName=mylocalhostname
```

How to export the `sed` command output into environment variables?

Comment: You should be using `$` not `#` for your variable.

Comment: `ApplicationName=#HOSTNAME` using `#` is kind of placeholder. due some other reason  i cann't use `$`

Answer (score 1):

> How to export the 'sed' command output into environment variables

You have to execute statements in your parent shell, not in a subshell run inside a pipeline (and a subshell that could be potentially run inside `xargs` to execute `export`).

Parsing `printenv` output seems like a horrible idea. Just iterate over the actual variables in actual bash:

```
for i in "${!jdbc_url@}"; do export "$i=${!i//#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME}"; done
```

In a perfectly *safe* environment, with newline separated and clean variables, you could:

```
eval "$(printenv | grep "#HOSTNAME" | sed "s/#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/1" | xargs -d'\n' printf "%q\n" | sed 's/^/export /')"
```

but you should be using zero separated streams. The following might would be okey-ish, I guess:

```
eval "$(printenv -0 | grep -z "#HOSTNAME" | sed -z "s/#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/1" | xargs -z printf "%q\0" | sed -z 's/^/export /; s/$/\n/')"
```

Recommended read would be [bash eval and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Och, you could also read lines, circumventing the need for eval:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
      export "$line";
done < <(printenv -0 | grep -z "#HOSTNAME" | sed -z "s/#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/1")
# or
readarray -d '' -t lines < <(printenv -0 | grep -z "#HOSTNAME" | sed -z "s/#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/1")
export "${lines[@]}"
```

Note that `grep "#HOSTNAME" | sed "s/#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/1"` is equal to `sed '/#HOSTNAME/!d; s//'"$HOSTNAME/1"`.

Comment: `xargs` doesn't run a shell at all, so `export` would never work with it.

Comment: So there's the word "potentially"

Comment: `for i in "${!jdbc_url@}"; do export "$i=${!i//#HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME}"; done` can you please share equivalent statement in `sh`

Comment: `jdbc_url` is referenced but not assigned. something I missing could please share the equivalent `sh` statement

Comment: There's no equivalent, bash extensions are extensions with no replacements. You could split "listing variables with a prefix" and templating them to separate parts - but i guess you'll end up parsing `printenv` or `env` anyway. There are other snippets in the answer to use instead. The solution using gnu tools still would work on posix shell. I could also imagine a safe solution with `xxd`.